# How to download the code for your Wordpress website, when you don't have access to FTP, but have administrative access to the Wordpress website?

Tags: wordpress, download, administrator

I have administrative access to the Wordpress website, but I do not have access to the FTP side.

Is there a way to download the code for the website just from the admin account?

Answer (score 0):

You can try UpdraftPlus plugin -> https://wordpress.org/plugins/updraftplus/

Answer (score 0):

There are Many free Plugin available.. you can use updraftPlus or you can use file manager plugin as well